# How to bring text to bottom in flutter without affecting other widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart

When ever i try to bring thee text "How many?" in the bottom of the screen little above the slider it gives this error called "bottom overflow by 31 pixels". Please help me fix it!

[App img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OUmO.jpg)

Code: https://gist.github.com/predak821/b2577839eec0e0da51acb9a9b96d8172

Answer (score 0):

Add `Spacer()` widget after first container

```
class SliderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SiderWidgetState createState() => new SiderWidgetState();
}

class SiderWidgetState extends State {
  int valueHolder = 20;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Text(
            'How many?',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
        Container(
          child: Slider(
            value: valueHolder.toDouble(),
            min: 1,
            max: 100,
            divisions: 100,
            activeColor: Colors.green,
            inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
            label: '${valueHolder.round()}',
            onChanged: (double newValue) {
              setState(() {
                valueHolder = newValue.round();
              });
            },
            semanticFormatterCallback: (double newValue) {
              return '${newValue.round()}';
            },
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          '$valueHolder',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: now how to bring the text to bottom? the "how many" text...

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 540, 0, 0),
```

Add a Spacer() between the two containers:

```
Container(
        // margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 0),
        child: Text(
          'How many?',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
        ),
      ),
Spacer(),
Container(...
```

Comment: how do i bring the text "how many?" also in the bottom of the screen, slightly above the slider?

Comment: Ok, then you must move the Spacer(), to the very first item. Dont forget to remove "margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 540, 0, 0)" line

Comment: You can preview my pen here: https://codepen.io/teddichiiwa/pen/poEzQyw

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Randomizer')),
            body: Center(child: SliderWidget())));
  }
}

class SliderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SiderWidgetState createState() => new SiderWidgetState();
}

class SiderWidgetState extends State {
  int valueHolder = 20;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, //<---Change
          children: [
          
      Container(
        // margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 0),
        child: Text(
          'How many?',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0), // <-------------Change Here
          child: Slider(
              value: valueHolder.toDouble(),
              min: 1,
              max: 100,
              divisions: 100,
              activeColor: Colors.green,
              inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
              label: '${valueHolder.round()}',
              onChanged: (double newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  valueHolder = newValue.round();
                });
              },
              semanticFormatterCallback: (double newValue) {
                return '${newValue.round()}';
              })),
      Text(
        '$valueHolder',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
      )
    ]));
  }
```

Try this out, This results in something like this. [image: remove padding]

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have hardcoded the margin with fixed values. Due to this even if you change value and fix it in your development screen, the issue will be seen in device of different screen size.

Instead if you want some widgets to be at the bottom of screen you can use Align:

```
Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: // your widget
      );
```

In Child you can put slider and the text you want under a Column widget.